# Why does the message embedded by Cooper in the second hand of the wristwatch run on a loop?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

At the end of Interstellar, when Cooper is trapped inside the Tesseract, he figures out a way to convey the quantum data recorded inside the singularity to his daughter Murph.

He does so by embedding the quantum data, translated in morse code, in the second hand of the wristwatch. This is the same wristwatch he gifted her while leaving planet earth.

**My Question**:

If Cooper has recorded the data in the second hand during a particular time period in his daughter's life, how come the lengthy pattern is running on a loop for Murph to find out about it later in her life?

Because any change made by him at *T* time inside the room cannot be expected to repeat infinitely otherwise the books that he pushed to say "STAY" will always be falling off the shelf.

I hope I made the question clear. If not please comment.